# Copy 20% of the total images

Tags: python

I want to copy images from one directory to another using Python. I don't want to copy all the images but only 20% of the total images - can anybody help me to do that? Thank you.

Comment: your code could start with `from random import choices`, or `from random import sample`. You can write the rest.

Comment: Just keep a counter of how many you've copied and stop when it's 20% of the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting 20% of the filenames

```
import random
import os

def get_random_images(path):
    file_names = os.listdir(path)
    shuffle = random.sample(file_names,len(file_names))
    twenty_percent_files = shuffle[::5]
    for i in range(len(twenty_percent_files)):
        yield twenty_percent_files[i]

files = get_random_images('/')
for f in files:
    print(f)

# now you have 20% of the filenames and you can move them
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Ev. Kounis comment in your question, what you want to do is make a list of files in a directory; take a look at [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.listdir).  Once you have the full list of files, you can use simple math to determine the number of files you want from the full list.  Once you have the number of files you want, [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.sample) is a great way to get that subset.

Hope this helps!